# Personally identifiable information in a PDF bank statement?

Tags: privacy, pdf

I have got to upload a sample bank statement PDF online which is going to accessible to everyone. I have obviously edited out all account details, names, codes, transaction particulars and the metadata from properties. The transaction amounts are still the same, and it's important they remain so.

Now, before uploading it online for everyone to see, I want to know if there could be anything I am missing. Could the bank have some special bytes to track who a particular statement belongs to that someone could misuse somehow? Or anything else out of my scope of thinking?

Comment: Best way is to make a screen shot/plain image of the document and then upload that (or make it a PDF and upload this). Having an plain image like PNG reduces the risk of leaking sensitive meta data or data that is still included in the PDF after editing.

Answer (score 1):

> Could the bank have some special bytes to track who a particular statement belongs to that someone could misuse somehow?

If it was not a generic PDF you've downloaded from somewhere but instead one you've downloaded while you were logged in, then it might be personalized to you and might contain information which might be used to associate the statement to you by others. These information might not be obvious - it might be some specific sentences, typos, spacing, font sizes ... which seem to be innocent but which are actually different for each personalized PDF. And they might be robust against printing and scanning since they are not actually hidden from view.

Also, if you've uploaded the PDF while being logged in or if you sent it from your email then these sender information might be associated by the recipient with this specific PDF too.